# Symfony 1.4 form widgets

Tags: forms, symfony1

I am using symfony1.4 with doctrine ORM. i have problem in edit form using formwidgets.
I successfully added a record using formWidgets. I am having a datatable with Edit and Delete link with the record id and i want to edit it using the formwidgets. 
I am passing the id to the form as like this

$this->form = new TblallusersForm($id);

But it is requesting for object. The problem is how can i pass the id to the form as object
Pl help me solve this.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve the object first, then pass that instance to the form:

```
$object = Doctrine_Core::getTable("Tblallusers")->find($id);
$this->form = new TblallusersForm($object);
```

Comment: In addition to this check http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10